# Splitting time to 10 mins interval in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to split the time in the interval of 30mins, so i can get time like this:

12:00 AM 12:10 AM 12:20 AM  .......... till 11:50 PM.

i'm trying something like this :

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate* fromTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:startTime];
NSDate* toTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:endTime];

NSLog(@"Start time %@",fromTime);
NSLog(@"End time %@",toTime);

NSDate *dateByAddingThirtyMinute;

dateByAddingThirtyMinute = [fromTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:1800];

NSString *formattedDateString;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];  
formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateByAddingThirtyMinute];  

NSLog(@"Time after 10 min %@",formattedDateString);
```

but i am able to print the first ten minute splitting ...
can any one help me how to loop it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code

```
    NSString *startTime = @"12:00 AM";  
    NSString *endTime = @"11:40 AM";


    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"]; 
    NSDate* fromTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:startTime]; 
    NSDate* toTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:endTime];
    NSDate *dateByAddingThirtyMinute ;
    NSTimeInterval timeinterval = [toTime timeIntervalSinceDate:fromTime];
    NSLog(@"time Int %f",timeinterval/3600);
    float numberOfIntervals = timeinterval/3600;
    NSLog(@"Start time %f",numberOfIntervals);

    for(int iCount = 0;iCount<numberOfIntervals*6 ;iCount ++)
    {
        dateByAddingThirtyMinute = [fromTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];
        fromTime = dateByAddingThirtyMinute;
        NSString *formattedDateString; 
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateByAddingThirtyMinute];
        NSLog(@"Time after 10 min %@",formattedDateString);
    }
```

Comment: This does not account for when hours are added or skipped because of Daylight Savings Time.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the other answers are wrong, because they do not account for daylight savings time.  To do that, you have to use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`:

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *endDate = ...;
NSDateComponents *diff = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[diff setMinute:0];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *tmp = startDate;

NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:tmp];

while ([tmp laterDate:endDate] == endDate) {
  [diff setMinute:[diff minute] + 10];
  tmp = [cal dateByAddingComponents:diff toDate:startDate options:0];
  [dates addObject:tmp];
}
```

In this code, I'm not actually running the `NSDate` objects through the `NSDateFormatter`, because that should happen at a different level.  This code is all about the underlying data (the Model), and `NSDateFormatter` usually operates at the user-visible level (the View).  Plus, it's generally more useful to have the raw data object than the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
int numberOfIntervals = [toDate timeIntervalSinceDate:fromDate]/(10*60);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntervals; i++) {
    NSDate *theDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:i * 60 * 10];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];  
    NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateByAddingThirtyMinute];
    NSLog(@"Time after 10 min %@",formattedDateString);
    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

Comment: my only concern with my code is the int numberOfIntervals = [toDate timeIntervalSinceDate:fromDate]/(10*60);
line as I'm not sure how the int will play out with division (sometimes it gets a little funky :P)

Comment: This does not account for when hours are added or skipped because of Daylight Savings Time.